# What Qt widget(s) to use for read-only, scrollable, collapsible, icon list

Tags: user-interface, qt, widget, qwidget

I'm relatively new to Qt, and am not entirely familiar with the out-of-the-box widgets. I have a somewhat (but not very) complex widget to create, and don't want to reinvent any wheels. What is the best QWidget to use as a starting point to subclass and/or QWidgets to use to compose my widget. Here is the end-result I am looking for (apologies for the crude drawing):

[image: Widget]
<sub>(source: [drmtempsoimages at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/drmtempsoimages/_/rsrc/1283546424882/home/widget.png?height=301&width=400))</sub>

Key points:

- All icons will take up the same size, say 128 x 128. Ignoring the category groupings, they should all align in a nice grid.
- The widget should expand to fill all the horizontal and vertical area it can take. Expanding / shrinking horizontally may increase / decrease the number of icons shown in each row.
- Icons are grouped, and those groups should be collapsible.
- If the height of the widget exceeds its space, a vertical scrollbar should appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're actually looking for some of the more esoteric options for a QListView/QListWidget.

At the top level, add `QTreeWidget` or `QTreeView` will give you the hierarchy you're looking for, as well as managing the scrolling area.

Each Listed Item of the (expanded) `QTreeXItem` will be a `QListView`/`QListWidget`, setting `setViewMode(QListView::IconMode)` on them.

EDIT:
Note that to get the precise look you wanted above, you'll probably have to use QListView and use a custom delegate, handling the drawing yourself (unless you can find a theme that will do exactly what you want). However, I've coded up a short PyQt solution below using the Q*Widget classes because they're shorter, and will still demonstrate how to get the right layout. If you're using C++, the same Qt function calls apply, but obviously you might have more or less bookkeeping.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class displayItem(QtGui.QWidget):  #A simple widget to display, just centers a digit in a 100x100 widget
    def __init__(self,num):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.size=100
        self.resize(self.size,self.size)
        self.setMinimumSize(self.size,self.size)
        self.text = num
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.drawText(self.size//2,self.size//2,str(self.text))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
widget.setWindowTitle('simple tree')

#Build the list widgets
treeItem1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(widget)
treeItem1.setText(0,"TreeWidget Parent")   #Sets the "header" for your [+] box

list1 = QtGui.QListWidget()                #This will contain your icon list
list1.setMovement(QtGui.QListView.Static)  #otherwise the icons are draggable
list1.setResizeMode(QtGui.QListView.Adjust) #Redo layout every time we resize
list1.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode) #Layout left-to-right, not top-to-bottom

listItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(list1)
listItem.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(100,100)) #Or else the widget items will overlap (irritating bug)
list1.setItemWidget(listItem,displayItem(1))

listItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(list1)     #Add a few more items
listItem.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(100,100))
list1.setItemWidget(listItem,displayItem(2))

listItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(list1)
listItem.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(100,100))
list1.setItemWidget(listItem,displayItem(3))

list1.setAutoFillBackground(True)                #Required for a widget that will be a QTreeWidgetItem widget
treeSubItem1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(treeItem1)  #Make a subitem to hold our list
widget.setItemWidget(treeSubItem1,0,list1)       #Assign this list as a tree item

treeItem2 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(widget)        #Make a fake second parent
treeItem2.setText(0,"TreeWidget Parent II")

widget.show()           #kick off the app in standard PyQt4 fashion
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How does one make each listed item a QListWidget? The only thing I see that one can use is QTreeWidgetItem, which seems to support only a fixed-column number of text and icons. Would I need to rebuild the entire tree on a form resize event, distributing the items along the column manually? Surely there is a better way....

Comment: There's a setItemWidget call... I've created a small PyQt example in the edit.